# What does this phrase mean, before or after?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I am reading a document and came through this confusing phrase:

> It is a possibility that numbers may change post customer committee pending review

FYI, I only replaced one word (commercials => numbers)

Does it mean that the numbers can be changed before sending it to the customers committee? Or it means that the customers committee can possibly change the numbers?

The next phrase is (it may provide context) :

> Your relationship manager will confirm that you are happy with the commercials before your application arrives at customer committee.

Comment: It is gobbledygook and subject to various interpretations.  But I would say that it means the thing might change after the committee meets, due to a review of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'post' means after, so it's definitely after the committee meets that they might end up changed - that is, it's the committee changes them.

It's also implicit that the review might change things again, although there are no details presented here on what limits that review might or might not have.